# Put white fill and color on the edges

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I needed to make a form that looks like this: https://milq.github.io/cursos/psp/ud/6/formulario.png. I am using boostramp and I am not able to set white background color and green border at the same time. 
Since I'm using bootstrap I think I can't use css and I'm not able to put both styles at the same time

I leave you my code.

```html
html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />       
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black">
        </br>  </br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" style="border: 20px solid green">                    
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend class="text-center header">Contact us</legend>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." rows="7"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col">                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         </br>  </br>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"></meta>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>

    <title>
        Getting Started: Handling Form Submission
    </title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>

            <div class="col-6" style="border: 20px solid green; background-color: lightgray;">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-center header">Contact us</legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
                                </span>

                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
                                </span>

                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i>
                                </span>

                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control"></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i>
                                </span>

                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control"></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i>
                                </span>

                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." rows="7"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg bg-success">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/fa2k4pL0/
Thanks!!!